# Android | Whatsapp - read last message

Tags: android, whatsapp

Lets say that I need the last message that sent to whatsapp app and I need to be able to read this message from my application. (TTS).

I know how to send message to Whatsapp from my app but not writing message from my app and send to Whatsapp with specific contact name.

Edit:

How can I read the last message that sent from contact in Whatsapp? I want to take the string of the last message and use it in my app.

Thank you guys.

Comment: can you show how are sending 'message to whatsapp from your app'?

Comment: http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/android/28000012

Comment: 'but not writing message from my app and send to whatsapp'? what does that mean? Not getting your language.